# How Can I Disable Pointer Mode For Xbox One (C#, UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbox, xbox-one

I was wondering how I could disable pointer mode on a UWP application. I already have XYFocusKeyboardNavigation set up and everything works perfectly when I plug my xbox one controller into my PC. Whenever I debug to my console I have a pointer instead of typical xbox controls. I have tried to disable it by adding the following commands but nothing worked, please help:

```
RequiresPointer="Never" //At Page Level

this.RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never; //On Load

RequiresPointerMode = "WhenRequested" //In App.xaml

this.RequiresPointerMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested; //tried on load but requirespointermode does not exist

Application.Current.RequiresPointerMode = ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested; //tried on load but got Error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I debug to my console I have a pointer instead of typical xbox controls. I have tried to disable it by adding the following commands but nothing worked, please help:
>   `this.RequiresPointerMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested; //tried on load but requirespointermode does not exist`

To turn off mouse mode, add the following to the constructor for your app

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.RequiresPointerMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

**Note:**

> If you are writing a C++/DirectX app, there's nothing to do. Mouse mode only applies to HTML and XAML applications.

For more details you could refer to [How to disable mouse mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode).

Comment: the definition this.RequiresPointerMode, Suspending  and OnSuspending dont exist.... i tried to do that a while ago. Any ideas?

Comment: The `RequiresPointerMode` is  `Application` property, you should write the above code in your `App.xaml.cs` file. Or it will throw compile error.

Comment: Thanks that worked.... The problem was as you said that i was trying to put the code in my main form instead of App.xaml.cs