# Hide mouse pointer for specific screen / control on Xbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbox-one

I have a UWP app running on Xbox One. The app uses mouse pointer for navigation. It works well. One screen contains a video player that can be set to run fullscreen. When in fullscreen video playback, the mouse pointer does not disappear.

How can I make the mouse pointer programmatically disappear when the player enters fullscreen and appear when it exits full screen?

I found [How Can I Disable Pointer Mode For Xbox One (C#, UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747821/how-can-i-disable-pointer-mode-for-xbox-one-c-uwp) but it only handles global pointer set when the app starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the media player in a custom user control on which you could say `RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never;` whenever the player enters fullscreen?

I don't have an Xbox here at the moment to test it and it's been a while since I've wrote something for it. But this approach would be my first guess.

Comment: I have the player in a user control but setting `RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never` on the user control or player does nothing

Answer (score 3):

Found a working solution, to hide the cursor, do `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null`. First store the value somewhere of course so you can restore it when you need the cursor back.